# Future dating entries not displaying when current

Tags: entry, future-entries, cache-breaking

Any future-dated entries are not displaying for me once the entry date is current. The exception is if I touch any entry in the channel (which is nice that it busts the cache, but it rather defeats the purpose of future dating). I have global caching enabled, but not on the template itself. Caching provides a nice speed improvement, so I'm hoping the answer isn't to disable it entirely.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" show_future_entries="no" limit="1" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" disable="categories|member_data"}
    Most recent: {title} - {entry_date format="%D, %F %d, %Y - %g:%i:%s"
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use cache in that case, as explain in [the doc](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html): "Enable this feature only if you do not use future entries, expiring entries, or random entries."

If you need cache, try to automatically clean up it every x minutes with a cron task or scheduled task.